# Python - Random dice

Tags: python, dice

I am a fairly new programmer, and I stumbled with a beginner practice project, a random dice number generator. The code works, but I would like to know if there is an efficient way compared to mine to write it.

```
#Random dice 
import random 

#returns a number (side of the dice)
def roll_dice():
  print (random.randint(1, 6)) 

print("""
Welcome to my python random dice program!
To start press enter!
Whenever you are over, type quit.
""")

flag = True
while flag:
   user_prompt = input(">")
   if user_prompt.lower() == "quit":
      flag = False
   else:
     print("Rolling dice...\nYour number is:") 
     roll_dice()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [You can make it look nicer!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Instead of writing comments in front of your functions, do it with docstrings:

```
def roll_dice():
    """Print a number between 1 and 6 (side of the dice)"""
    print(random.randint(1, 6))
```

You can observe that I made a couple of changes to this:

- removed the extra space you had in your `print()` function
- added the docstring I mentioned above
- modified the content of docstring (your function doesn't return anything, it just prints a random number). A beginner programmer might get the wrong idea.
- used 4-spaces indentation instead of two.
- 2 new lines in front of your function

#### Now, let's try to make it even better!

You have two [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), 1 and 6. Since you put the logic inside a function, let's make use of it and define those as arguments to our function:

```
def roll_dice(min_dice, max_dice):
    """Print a number between min_dice and max_dice (side of the dice)"""
    print(random.randint(min_dice, max_dice))
```

The above has the advantage of an easier customization of your program. More, you can abstract things even more, and give those arguments a default value:

```
def roll_dice(min_dice=1, max_dice=6):
    """Print a number between min_dice and max_dice (side of the dice)"""
    print(random.randint(min_dice, max_dice))
```

More, you can go a step further and make the function actually do something. Let's make it so that it returns a value. Just replace the `print()` function with `return`.

Okay, so far so good. I think we've managed to handle this part pretty well. Let's move on.

First, let's apply the changes we did in the first part, to this one too:

```
print("""
Welcome to my python random dice program!
To start press enter!
Whenever you are over, type quit.
""")

flag = True
while flag:
    user_prompt = input(">")
    if user_prompt.lower() == "quit":
        flag = False
    else:
        print("Rolling dice...\nYour number is:")
        roll_dice()
```

What I don't like about this, is the fact that you didn't wrap the logic inside a function. Let's do that first:

```
def play():
    print("""
    Welcome to my python random dice program!
    To start press enter!
    Whenever you are over, type quit.
    """)
    flag = True
    while flag:
        user_prompt = input("> ")
        if user_prompt.lower() == "quit":
            flag = False
        else:
            print("Rolling dice...\nYour number is:")
            roll_dice()
```

The changes that I'd like to make to this function are the following:

- remove the `flag` variable
- move out the intro message in it

  ```
  def play():
      while True:
          user_prompt = input("> ")
          if user_prompt.lower() == "quit":
              return False
          else:
              print("Rolling dice...\nYour number is: {}".format(roll_dice()))
  ```

Moving next, let's build our `main()` function:

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to my python random dice program!\n"
          "To start press ENTER!\n"
          "Whenever you are over, type quit.\n")
    play()
```

Last but not least, let's call our main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can see I added an extra line: `if __name__ == "__main__"`. By doing the main check, you can have that code only execute when you want to run the module as a program and not have it execute when someone just wants to import your module and call your functions themselves.

---

The full code:

```
import random


def roll_dice(min_dice=1, max_dice=6):
    """Print a number between min_dice and max_dice (side of the dice)"""
    return random.randint(min_dice, max_dice)


def play():
    """Return false if user enters 'quit'. Otherwise, print a random number"""
    while True:
        user_prompt = input("> ")
        if user_prompt.lower() == "quit":
            return False
        else:
            print("Rolling dice...\nYour number is: {}".format(roll_dice()))


def main():
    print("Welcome to my python random dice program!\n"
          "To start press ENTER!\n"
          "Whenever you are over, type quit.\n")
    play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Since there is no specific tag on the question, it's probably worth noting that this is ok in python 3, while in python 2 `raw_input()` should be used.

Comment: A simple way to fix ChatterOne's problem is to use the try: `try: input = raw_input except NameError: pass`. But I think it's reasonably safe to believe OP is using Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've learned a lot (btw I'm using python 3).